# Perform pushViewController from inside the AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift3, uiviewcontroller, navigation, appdelegate

In my iOS app, I want to open a new view controller, on arrival of a push notification event. I tried following inside AppDelegate.swift to handle navigation.

```
let friendStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Profile", bundle: nil)
let friendsVC = friendStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FriendsViewIdentifier") as! FriendsViewController
let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
backItem.title = ""
self.window?.rootViewController?.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
self.window?.rootViewController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(friendsVC, animated: true)
```

But still it can't handle navigation of View Controller. How can I make this work?

so in this case my view controller hierarchy does not contains a UiNavigationController. the hierarchy is as below.

[image]

Comment: One of more of these might be nil: `window`, `rootViewController`, `navigationController`. Check whether they are nil first.

Comment: Be sure self.window?.self.window?.rootViewController? is UINavigationController, think this is returning nil .

Answer (score 1):

Else block will give you an answer.

```
if let friendStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Profile", bundle: nil) {
        if let friendsVC = friendStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FriendsViewIdentifier") as? FriendsViewController {

            let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
            backItem.title = ""
            self.window?.rootViewController?.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem

            if let navController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
                navController.pushViewController(friendsVC, animated: true)
            } else if let tabController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {

                if let tabViewControllers = tabController.viewControllers {

                    if let navController = tabViewControllers.first as? UINavigationController {
                        navController.pushViewController(friendsVC, animated: true)

                    } else {
                        print("tabViewControllers.first as? UINavigationController not found")
                    }

                }  else {
                    print("tabViewControllers count is zero")
                }

            } else {
                print("UINavigationController & UITabBarController not found at self.window?.rootViewController")
            }

        } else {
            print("FriendsViewController not found")
        }

    } else {
        print("friendStoryboard not found")
}
```

Comment: ok, it prints "UINavigationController not found at self.window?.rootViewController".and instead of a UINavigationController it contains a tab bar controller. so how can I navigation to another view controller from there.

Comment: i'll add the view controller hierarchy.

Comment: It prints UINavigationController & UITabBarController not found at self.window?.rootViewController

Comment: <AX.StartTabBarController: 0x125d21760> this is custom tab bar extended from UITabBarController